# Jquery RSS Reader

Tags: xml, ajax, jquery

Ok so im trying to pull RSS fedd only using Jquery from a website but does not seem to be working.

http://jackrsharp.com/sandbox/test2.html

View Source code

I can not make it read XML or RSS files from the internet, but i can from a local XML file on the same server.

Any help or simple guides would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to download data from another domain because ["Same Origin Policy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: You can setup a proxy page on the same domain, the proxy page will grab data from internet

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this _is_ an answer. Without the link it would still answer  the question.